# Upload files using Zend Error

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I am trying to upload files following [Zend's tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html), but keep getting this error:

```
[10-Apr-2015 05:14:41 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Album\Controller\UploadForm' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php on line 120
```

Comment: Can you please share the controller? Also: the title is not quite correct: "using Zend Error" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you forgot to use Your UploadForm class on top of controller class. So in that case when you call directly call Form class from controller it searched into current namespace which is Album\Controller so error coming.

Change it to (Assuming your form class at Album/Form/).

```
namespace Album\Controller;

use Album\Form\UploadForm;
```